# Collecting old objects from java heap

Tags: java, garbage-collection, native-code, eclipse-memory-analyzer

I have Order_Item class instance, and these are paths to GC Roots (excluding phantom/weak/soft references):
[image]

I have few questions:
1) I'm not sure if the Order_Item will be garbage collected.
I tried to run System.gc(), and the object remained in heap.
Is it allowed to be collected, according to provided image?

2) What "Native Stack" mean?
As far as I understood, it's accounted as GC root.
http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.mat.ui.help%2Fconcepts%2Fgcroots.html
Why some object (i.e. Order 0x782032cf8) is kept in "Native Stack"?

3) If I have reference from GC Root to object A, that object will not be garbage collected? Right?
And if so, my Order_Item object can't be garbage collected?

4) If 3 is right, how may I find what keeps objects 0x7821da5e0 and 0x782032cf8, and how to dereference/remove them?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot really force the garbage collector to delete a given object. You know that the object is kept alive as long as it is reachable by references from the given point in the program. But if the object gets "collectable", it might be collected soon, but if there is no pressure on memory, it may fool around for a long time.

Usually, there is not reason to really delete objects if there is enough memory. The only exception I know are passwords. Here, you use a char array and overwrite it with nonsense once you used it.

For the native stack: Your link indicates that the native stack keeps external resources, e.g. files.

Comment: Honestly, I didn't understand your answer. My colleague too.

Comment: I will explain it more thoroughly but give me a hint what you do not understand.

Comment: My questions is structured, so that I will understand not only the current case, but future cases too. It wold be great to get answers in the same manner. 1) You know .... the program. - So the answer is no? 2,3,4 - unanswered.

Comment: I am sorry, I did not address the different parts of your question directly. What I wanted to tell you is that there is no certain way to remove an object from the heap. You can ALLOW the garbage collector to take it (by setting all references to it to null or letting the objects that point to it go out of scope), but it might not do it.

Comment: If you want to find out which classes use your object, you might be better of using the call hierarchy in eclipse than searching through the heap.

Comment: Call hierarchy is used only with methods, as far as I know. And it's only for methods that call selected one. If I have few hundred calls to the method, it's pretty difficult to pass one by one, and check for leaks, ie.

Comment: Usually, I search for the constructor calls with call hierarchy and try to minimize the lifetime of the constructed objects. If your class is used in extremely many places, this might be time consuming. I'm sorry I could not help you with your problem.